# Python pointers or queue share

Tags: python

Before I used C, now I want to learn Python.

I have a question, I have two class, how can I pass a variable address when I call the constructor, because I want to share a Queue between this two class( each class has a thread). Or does it have any other options to share a queue between two class.

Comment: Python has Queue module that is thread safe

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)? It covers all the basics quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python already uses reference (as opposed to value) semantics:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print b # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You don't have to do any extra work to get what you want.

Comment: I would prefer *Python has reference semantics* over *Python uses pointers internally* - the latter is implementation specific.

Comment: A fair point, @Space_C0wb0y, and that's why you have the ability to edit my answer. :)

Comment: Also a fair point. I tend to be very reluctant to edit answers (much more so than questions), but there is not really a good reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

However if you're talking about threading, that's another story. If you are talking specifically about the `multiprocessing` `Queue` inter-thread communication protocol, that may copy data over. Your best bet might be the `Manager` shared-memory communication protocol described in http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: The first two sentences are wrong. Everything is an object in Python, and everything is passed exactly the same way.

Comment: @kindall thank you, you indeed seem to be correct. I have just confirmed this by doing `z=(1+99999)` and `assert z is (lambda x:x)(z)`. I have removed the incorrect statements.

Comment: You will run into some fun quirks if you dig a little deeper. For example, Python reuses objects for small integers, to save memory.

Comment: @kindall: that is exactly why I did `(1+99999)` =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your question, but can't you just pass it as parameter to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is an object. There is no need to worry about "pointers" in Python.

```
foo = []

def bar(val):
  val.append(42)

def baz(val):
  val.append('Hello, world!')

bar(foo)
print foo
baz(foo)
print foo
```